# A question of free vector space generated by S

Tags: vector-spaces

Suppose that $S = \{s_1, s_2\}$ for arbitrary elements $s_1, s_2 \in S$ and $s_1 \ne s_2$, and let $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{Z}_2$. Define $\mathcal{F}(S;\mathbb{F})$ to be "*free vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ generated by $S$*".

What is $\mathcal{F}(S;\mathbb{Z}_2)$ explicitly? What is the "basis" from this free vector space?
I am thinking that $\mathcal{F}(S;\mathbb{Z}_2) = \{as_1+bs_2 \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_2 \,\ \land \,\ s_1,s_2 \in S\}$.

I am thinking that the basis is the set $\{s_1, s_2\}$ because every element in $\mathcal{F}(S;\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is of the form $$v = \sum^{n}_{i=1} a_i s_i$$ where $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $s_i \in S$. But, is this true?

### Edit:

If $S = \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{Z}_3$, is $\dim(\mathcal{F}(S, \mathbb{F}))$ is countably infinite?

Comment: You’re correct. This space has only four elements, so it’s easy to see that $S$ is a basis.

Comment: for any field $F$ and any set $S$, $S$ forms a basis for the free vector space over $F$ generated by $S$. so indeed your reasoning in the first question is correct and the answer to your second question is yes